# How do you mock dynamically added object methods?

Tags: python

I'm trying to mock external API calls in the [pyonfleet](https://github.com/onfleet/pyonfleet) package. My desired usage is something like below.

```
def get_task(id):
    from onfleet import Onfleet
    api = Onfleet()
    return api.tasks.get(id=id)

with patch('onleet.Onfleet.tasks.get', return_value={}):
    task = get_task(id='...')
```

The problem is the `tasks` attribute and it's API endpoints are set on the `Onfleet` object using `setattr` in its `_initialize_resources` method. Because of this all my tests are raising the error:

> AttributeError: type object 'Onfleet' has no attribute 'tasks'

```
class Onfleet(object):
    # Loading config data
    data = Config.data
    # Look up local authentication JSON if no api_key was passed
    if (os.path.isfile(".auth.json")):
        with open(".auth.json") as json_secret_file:
            secret = json.load(json_secret_file)

    def __init__(self, api_key=None):
        self._session = requests.Session()
        # auth takes api_key and api_secret
        self._session.auth = (api_key if api_key else self.secret["API_KEY"], "")
        self._initialize_resources(self._session)

    def auth_test(self):
        path = self.data["URL"]["base_url"] + self.data["URL"]["version"] + self.data["URL"]["auth_test"]
        response = self._session.get(path)
        return response.json()

    def _initialize_resources(self, session):
        resources = self.data["RESOURCES"]
        # Go through the config module to create endpoints
        for endpoint, http_methods in resources.items():
            setattr(self, endpoint, Endpoint(http_methods, session))
```

How do I patch methods on an object that are added dynamically?

Comment: Is `tasks` actually a class attribute, or is it an instance attribute? You'll probably have to mock `Onfleet` itself. I'd save myself the trouble and rewrite `get_task` to take an instance of `Onfleet` (or at least the class `Onfleet` itself) as an argument, rather than making you resort to mocking by hardcoding the reference to `Onfleet`.

Comment: @chepner, yeah it's an instance attribute. I like that idea - thanks.